# Javascript, var contains

Tags: javascript, contains

I currently use this script:

```
wHandle.setNick = function (arg) {
    userNickName = arg;
    var fnicks = ["porno","ibne","amcÄ±k","amcik","piÃ§","salak","orospu","pkk","sik","kÃ¼rdistan","kurdistan","kÃœrdistan","kÃ¼rt","sikeyim","sÄ±keyim","gÃ¶toÅŸ","yÃ¶netici","YÃ–NETICI","YONETICI","yonetici","admÄ±n","admin","yarah","yarrah","agario","sike","s1ke","anan"];
    var nctr = arg.toLowerCase();
            if(fnicks.indexOf(nctr) > -1) {
        alert("Unknown Nickname!");
        } else {
    hideOverlays();
    sendNickName();
    wjQuery("#mini-map-wrapper").show();
    userScore = 0
    wjQuery(".btn-needs-nick").prop("disabled", false);
     }     
};
```

I wanted to make some kind of filter, so that it blocks these nicknames BUT it isn't covering all of my cases. For example it blocks **porno** but not **pornoo**

I want it to use `if(contains)`.

Comment: what? Your code is supposed to work.

Comment: Iterate through the fnicks array and check for each string in the array, if nctr is a substring, until you find one. Take a look at the String and Array entries at developer.mozilla.org for hints about how to do that in detail.

Comment: yeah im not really sure, it checks if it matches, but it just doesnt use CONTAINS

Answer (score 0):

well I would just loop through the array, and search if the argument you pass (nctr in that case) contains the current entry (`fnicks[i]`).
you can replace the `console.log()` by your usual `alert()`

```
var arg = "pornoo";        
var fnicks = ["porno","ibne","amcÄ±k","amcik","piÃ§","salak","orospu","pkk","sik","kÃ¼rdistan","kurdistan","kÃœrdistan","kÃ¼rt","sikeyim","sÄ±keyim","gÃ¶toÅŸ","yÃ¶netici","YÃ–NETICI","YONETICI","yonetici","admÄ±n","admin","yarah","yarrah","agario","sike","s1ke","anan"];
var nctr = arg.toLowerCase();
for(var i=0,c=fnicks.length;i<c;i++) {
    if(nctr.indexOf(fnicks[i]) > -1) {
        console.log('boom'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially done your logic backwards. Instead of checking if the nickname is in your block list, you'd be better served checking if an element of your blocklist is in your nickname like so:

```
var nick = args.toLowerCase();
for (var i; i < fnicks.length; i++) {
  if (nick.indexOf(fnicks[i]) != -1) {
    //bad name!
  }
}
```